# Bash loop - creating a folder for each existing txt file in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have text files in a directory that I want to organize. I am trying to do so thru bash by creating a directory for each file. As I move the file to its respective new folder, I want to modify the original `filename` and create an additional text file labeld `info.txt` that holds the original file name(this file is also place in the new folder). The files name change goes from `xxx-file_name-aa1.txt` to `xxx-aa1.txt`. Anything between the first and last `-` is stripped out. The folder has the same name as the file `xxx-aa1`.

test.sh (my sed statement strips whitspaces and turns everything to lower case  except anything after the last `-`

```
FILE_PATH="/media/sf_linux_sandbox/txt_files/"
while read -r file; do
#sed statement empty
new_name=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\(-[^-]*\)$/\L\1\E\2/; s/ *- */-/; s/^\(.*\) \+- *\([^-]*\)$/\1-\2/; s/ /_/g')
mv "$file" "$new_name"
done < <(find $FILE_PATH -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt')
```

Input:

```
|-- ./
|   |-- xxxx-test_file1-aa1.txt
|   |-- xxxx-test_file2-bb2.txt
```

Desired Output:

```
|-- ./
|   |-- xxxx-aa1
|       |--xxx-aa1.txt
|       |--info.txt // contains name 'test_file1'
|   |-- xxxx-bb2
        |--xxx-bb2.txt
        |--info.txt // contains name 'test_file2'
```

Current Output

```
|-- ./
|   |-- xxxx-test_file-aa1
|       |--xxxx-test_file-aa1.txt
|   |-- xxxx-test_file-bb2
        |--xxxx-test_file-bb2.txt
```

Comment: Your test cases don't address the lowercase functionality at all.  Also, you have `new_name` but then move to `new_file`.  Finally, your `find` loop has `.mp4` files, but your pseudo-example shows `.txt` files.

Comment: @triplee, sorry I had tested out with mp4 files as well and forgot to revert my pseudo code all the way for txt files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do all these manipulations in Bash itself.

Since you have `-maxdepth 1` it looks like you can just use a wildcard loop instead of `find` so I refactored that, too.

```
FILE_PATH="/media/sf_linux_sandbox/videos/"
for file in "$FILE_PATH"/*.mp4; do
    tmp=${file#*-}; head=${file%-"$tmp"}
    mid=${tmp%-*}; tail=${tmp#"$mid"-}
    base="${head,,}-${tail,,}"
    dir=${base%.mp4}
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$file" "$dir/$base"
    echo "$mid" >"$dir"/info.txt
done
```

Briefly, `${var#prefix}` expands to the value of `var` with `prefix` removed, and `${var%suffix}` correspondingly performs the same substitution with a suffix. Finally, `${var,,}` produces the lowercase version of the value. Then we simply assemble the file name structure you want from those parts.

Comment: Very clear, tested it out but it breaks if the file has more than one hyphen `-` in the name. For example `xxxx-test_file-1-aa1` does not convert to `xxxx-aa1` but instead `xxxx-1`. What only matter for the new folder/file name is what comes before the first `-` and what comes after the last `-`.

Comment: Refactored to work for file names with arbitrary number of dashes (but will be erratic with less than two).  For historical reference, the earlier version used `IFS=-` and `set` to split the file name, but was hard-coded for exactly two dashes.

Comment: Oh did not know `IFS=-` and `set` was exactly for two dashes. It all makes sense now. Well explained!

Comment: It's not like they can't be made to work, but refactoring made the code simpler by switching to prefix/suffix instead.

Comment: Ok ran this, works well and as intended. I wasn't really specific in the name format of the file and now I am seeing an issue with files that have this type of name `xxxx-test_file-caa-v3u` (more than two `-` in the ending). I made a [NEW QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557550/extracting-unique-id-from-file-name)

Answer (score 1):

change the `sed` as

```
new_name=$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/-[^-]*-/-/g')
```

eg:

```
$ echo xxxx-test_file-aa1.txt | sed -r 's/-[^-]*-/-/g'
xxxx-aa1.txt
```

`-[^-]*-` selects the string between two `-` , sed `s` replace it with `-`

Also you can use `grep` command to get the name of the directory as

```
$ echo $new_name | grep -o '^[^.]*'
xxxx-aa1
```

`^[^.]*` selects the portion in filename, that doesnt contain `.` that is ommits the extension.

EDIT

To get the name of the file

```
$ echo "xxx-test_file-aa1.txt" | grep -oP '(?<=-)[^.]*(?=-)'
test_file
```

`(?<=-)` lookbehind assertion checks if the pattern is preseced by `-`

`(?=-)` lookahead assertion checks if the pattern is followed by `-`

`[^.]*` pattern matches anything other than `.`, selects the filename

Comment: Great! Closer to my goal. How would I be able to take what is in the between `-` and output to txt file. For example `xxxx-test_file-aa1.txt` take `test_file_aa1` and output to `info.txt`

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, Just meant to grab what is between the `-` and last `-` so it would be just `test_file`. It should work if the file has more than two `-` like this `xxxx-test_file-1-aa1` to `test_file-1`

Comment: shouldnt it be `xxxx-test_file1-aa1` as in original question?

Comment: i have corrected that in the answer. assuming that `xxxx-test_file1-aa1` is the file name and not `xxxx-test_file-1-aa1` as in your previous comment. If the edit is wrong kindly point out :)