# Extracting unique id from file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am organizing text files in a directory by placing them in subdirectories. The subdirectory name is derived from the original file name. In this way it would be easy to tell which file belongs to its respective folder.  The bash `for loop` iterates through all the txt files and creates the folder accordingly.  The text files have the following example format: `xxxx-test_file1-aa1-a2.txt` or `xxxx-test_file1-aa1--2.txt`. Based on the first example, the only two things that matter for the name of the about to be created folder is `xxxx` and `-aa1-a2`(always have a 6 character unique id at the end). Therefore the new folder would be named `xxxx-aa1-a2`. The below only works for extracting the right name for certain files and breaks with other.

```
FILE_PATH="/my_files/"
for file in "$FILE_PATH"/*.txt; do
    tmp=${file#*-}; head=${file%-"$tmp"}
    mid=${tmp%-*}; tail=${tmp#"$mid"-}
    base="${head,,}-${tail,,}"
    dir=${base%.txt}
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$file" "$dir/$base"
done
```

`${var#prefix}` expands to the value of var with prefix removed, and `${var%suffix}` correspondingly performs the same substitution with a suffix. Finally, `${var,,}` produces the lowercase version of the value. Then we simply assemble the file name structure you want from those parts.

The above works if the file only has two `-`: `xxxx-test_file-aaasw1` or `xxxx-test_file-bswb2u`

```
|-- ./
|   |-- xxxx-aaasw1
|       |--xxxx-test_file-aaasw1.txt
|   |-- xxxx-bswb2u
        |--xxxx-test_file-bswb2u.txt.
```

But it breaks if the file has more than  two `-`:`xxxx-test_file-caa-v3u` or `xxxx-test_file-caa-v3-`

```
|-- ./
|   |-- xxxx-v3u
|       |-- xxxx-test_file-caa-v3u.txt
|   |-- xxxx-
        |-- xxxx-test_file-caa-v3-.txt.
```

Comment: Is xxxx always 4 characters long?

Comment: @hoipolloi yes `xxxx` is always `4` characters long and the ending `bswb-u` unique id is `6` characters long.

Comment: Earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540919/bash-loop-creating-a-folder-for-each-existing-txt-file-in-a-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want the directory to be named "a-b", where a is everything up to the first dash and b is everything between the last dash and the first dot?

```
touch xxxx-test_file-aaasw1
touch xxxx-test_file-bswb2u
touch xxxx-test_file-caa-v3u.txt
touch xxxx-test_file-caa-v3-.txt

for f in *
do
    head=$(cut -f1  -d'-' <<< "$f")
     mid=$(cut -f2  -d'-' <<< "$f")
    tail=$(cut -f3- -d'-' <<< "$f" | cut -f 1 -d .)
     ext=$(cut -f3- -d'-' <<< "$f" | cut -f 2- -d .)
    echo "[$head][$mid][$tail][$ext]"
    mkdir "${head}-${tail}"
    mv "${f}" "${head}-${tail}/${head}-${tail}.${ext}"
    echo "${mid}" > "${head}-${tail}"/title_info.txt
done

tree
```

Outputs:

```
|-- xxxx-aaasw1
|   `-- xxxx-test_file-aaasw1
|-- xxxx-bswb2u
|   `-- xxxx-test_file-bswb2u
|-- xxxx-caa-v3-
|   `-- xxxx-test_file-caa-v3-.txt
`-- xxxx-caa-v3u
    `-- xxxx-test_file-caa-v3u.txt
```

There are several other ways to go about this, but the ones I can think of are more cryptic than this straightforward, but not terribly efficient, approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63616/discussion-between-code-ed-student-and-bishop).

Comment: sorry to bother again but this failed when the file has more than two `-` a real example `xx-Official_linux_facts_101_-_Advanced_Mode-YSp8Z.txt` resulted to `xx-Advanced_Mode-YSp8Z` and not `xx-YSp8Z`

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student The code handles more than 2 dashes.  The problem is where the additional dash lies: potentially 2 dashes in the tail and potentially dashes in mid.  These are incompatible.  It *may* be sufficient to rename mid dashes of the form `_-_`, but I wouldn't count on it.  (Note in an earlier comment xxxx was always 4 and tail was always 6, but not all samples fit that pattern. My solution only requires there be no dashes in the mid. Some scenarios need manual handling; this sounds like one of them. Just get rid of the dash in mid by hand. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `mid` assignment so that it always trims six characters after the dash, followed by dot and extension.

```
mid=${tmp%-??????.*};
```

Comment: Yours is still the best solution!